# How to solve string index out of bounds exception

Tags: java

I'm making some methods for a hangman game for class. I'm trying to make an updated clue that shows the letters that were guessed correctly. Whenever I run the program I get a string index out of bounds exception and I don't know how to fix it.

```
 private String makeClue( String word )
    {
        int length = word.length();
        String clue = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < length ; i++)
        {
            clue += ("_ ");
        }
        return clue;
    }
        
    }
    
    private String updateClue( String clue, String word, String letter )
    {
        String update = " ";
        char guess = letter.charAt(0);
        int l = word.length();
        for(int i = 0; i <= l; i++)
        {
            if(word.charAt(i) == guess)
            {
                update = update + guess;
            }
            else
            {
                int index = i * 2;
                char thing = clue.charAt(index);
                update = update + thing;
            }
            
        }
```

This is the error that I get:

[image]

Comment: A String with a length of `x` has indexes going from `0` to `x - 1`. eG the String `"Test"` has a length of `4` and the indexes `0`, `1`, `2` and `3`. So you need to stop your loop before it reaches the value of `word.length()` and change `i <= l` to `i < l`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i <= l; i++)
{
    if(word.charAt(i) == guess)
```

when i is equal to l, i will be the length of `word`, and word.charAt(i) will be out of bounds (since the index (i) in this function is 0 based)

To understand better

```
String test = "a";
char c1 = test.charAt(0); // this will be "a"
char c2 = test.charAt(1); // this is out of bounds - there's no character after "a"
```